# Proyecto angular a IIS

Tags: angular5, iis, vscode

quiero subir un proyecto angular a un servidor IIS, todo correcto logre que subiera siguiendo los pasos de la carpeta "**DIST**" pero en mi proyecto no uso el index.html del proyecto si no mas bien los component.html con sus respectivos component.TS, el caso es que cuando subo el "**DIST**" al servidor este solo sube al index.html y no encuentro la forma de que me dirige a unos de mis component.html.

Que puedo hacer?

Comment: cuando generas dist es porque ya son los archivos de produccion o de pruebas, angular o el ng cli une todos tus componentes y vistas, por eso que veas solo `index,html`, `styles.css`, `main.js` , `polyfill.js` y la carpeta de assets. Lo que podrias hacer si quieres ver los componentes x separada es usar angular elements y crear las vistas para despues subirlas a IIS

Comment: Lo solucione modificando el index tenia una etiqueta <base href="/"> le quite el / y se soluciono. lo malo es que no es funcionar la pagina

Comment: ¿Con qué instrucción generaste los archivos del proyecto Angular en el directorio `dist`?